# How do I replace Spring Events with Project Reactor

Tags: java, spring, publish-subscribe, project-reactor

Let's say I have a huge Spring application. In one part of it some kind of business logic is perfromed. I need to perfom also some additional operations (e.g. re-calculate some metric and persist it to DB) which should not affect a main process. For that purpose I use the Spring Event mechanism (in async mode of course).

```
@Service
public class MyService {
   @Autowired
   private ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

   public void doSomeUsefulStuffWithEntity(Long entityId) {
   //some operation here

   eventPublisher.publishEvent(new EntityHasChangedEvent(Long entityId));
   }
}


@Component
public class MyEventListener {
   @Async
   @EventListener
   public void onEntityEvent(EntityHasChangedEvent event) {
      //do some stuff here
   }
}
```

Quite straitforward, isn't it. But there is an opinion that Spring Events were made mostly for Bean Lifecycle purposes, not for the business tasks. Hence the question. What is adequate replacement for my needs? Should I use a Publisher-Subscriber mechanism represented by Project Reactor. If so, how should it look? Spring Events gives me a weak cohesion between different domain modules - and I have no idea how to implement the same weak cohesion with Fluxes.

Comment: Change your opinion as that is wrong. Spring Security, amongst others, use it to publish authentication/autorization events. Spring itself publishes events about the requests being handled etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Project Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/) is a library designed to build non-blocking applications on the JVM. This is done mostly for performance reasons, see either the Project Reactor docs or for a deep dive read [State of Loom](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Erpressler/loom/loom/sol1_part1.html).

[Publish–subscribe pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) has nothing to do with non-blocking applications, it's a messaging pattern suitable for event broadcasting.

Since these two things are not comparable you can't really replace one with another.

Comment: But Project Reactor if also an implementation of the pub-sub pattern. Are we speaking about the different pub-subs?

Comment: Apache Kafka or Amazon SNS are also using pub-sub pattern, but I would not use them them to re-implement Spring events because just like Reactor their goal is something else.